# Laravel: How to paginate eloquent “hasMany” relationship from Model class?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function prices() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Price', 'product_id')->orderBy('purchase_date', 'desc');
    }
}
```

I want to use this in my blade - {{ $product->prices->render() }}

Comment: What `render()` method should return (i.e. html/json/text)? Have you defined it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

in your controller `$prices = $product->prices()->paginate();` and just return it to view or api

Comment: In my controller sir I have a collection of products "$products = Product::orderBy('name')->get();". In my blade I loop through prices in every product, it seems that I can't use your solution because you are creating prices collection in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a relationship between Product and Price

```
public function prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Price', 'product_id');
}
```

Now, in your Product Controller, you can query like

```
Product::with('prices')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

and now you can use it in your blade view with pagination, hope this answers your question

Comment: I returns an error sir "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'purchase_date' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `products` order by `purchase_date` desc limit 10 offset 0)"

Comment: I've edited my post now it will run the reason of this error is because product table doesn't have a column name purchase_date